# Why use srand when rand() generates all random numbers in C

Tags: c

I am generating random numbers , and someone told me to use srand. I searched about srand and found it is used on top of rand(). But I do not understand why not use just rand() since I get random numbers in my below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("random number is %d\n",rand());
    }
}
```

And I get a set of 5 random numbers. So rand() does gives random numbers. Why do we need srand on top of that then?

Comment: The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) should explain what happens when srand is *not* explicitly called first.

Comment: tons of duplicates here already explained that

Comment: See also [`srand()` — why call it only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833)

Answer (score 2):

If you simply use rand() and run your code multiple times you will notice that you tend to get the same sequence of random numbers every time.

`srand` is used to seed the random number generator.  This allows you to generate different sequences.  I'd suggest that you read [the manual page for srand.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand)

Comment: You use `srand` to generate `semi-random` numbers with a `seed` to produce a **reproducible** random set to allow debugging, etc.